# winform ComboBox autocomplete cache

Tags: c#-4.0, caching, autocomplete, combobox

I have a combo box bound to a DataTable. After making a selection in the combox, I update the datasource (i.e., filter the DataTable) and rebind it to the combox.

Everything works fine except for the autocomplete feature.

For example,
Lets say the datasource has values **12345, 12346, 12347**. Now I type 123, so the autocomplete shows all the 3 values. I selected one from the list. The code below then updates the datasource and reloads the combobox.

```
cmbType.DataSource = dtRequestTypes.Select("Some_Condition").CopyToDataTable();
cmbType.DisplayMember = "TypeOfReq";
cmbType.ValueMember = "TypeOfReq";
cmbType.Text = "";
```

Lets say the new datasource has values **abcde, abcef, abceg**. Now if I simply press the down arrow (without pressing any other buttons), "123" shows as selected text and it cycles the previous 3 values(**12345, 12346, 12347**) when I keep pressing the down arrow. If I click the dropdown arrow, it shows the new values and from now on the autocomplete works fine.

I believe the old values are stored in cache somewhere. Is there anyway to refresh it. I used **.Refresh()**, **.SelectedText=""**, **.Text=""**. Nothing works.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of AutoCompleteSource property? Did you call EndUpdate after reloading data?

Comment: I have set the AutoCompleteSource property to ListItems and I tried EndUpdate. Still not working.

Comment: I added the following lines before reloading the data and its working now. `cmbType.DataSource = null;
            cmbType.Items.Clear();`